# Django: ¿Is it better to load choices field dynamically or to create a Foreign Key model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the case where I want a model to have a lot of choices and right now I dont have that information persisted in my database. This information is the link between the urls and the views related to them in my application. I was trying to override the ModelAdmin to show all of this choices loaded dynamically but surprisingly, for me, I couldn't do that because the model field choices are evaluated just once. That kept me wondering about if it's a good idea to load this choices right in the model dynamically. After that, I read from the django docs that choices are meant to be unvariable data. And this choices, because of it's conceptualization (url and view linked to it) are necessarily going to increase.

So, my question is: ¿is there a good way to load the choices of a field in Django or should I just create a ForeignKey for this choices?

Comment: If they are meant to grow, why do you refrain from making a model for them? Just make a model for this data, point a foreign key to it from your other model... Wait "_This information is the link between the urls and the views related to them in my application_" by this do you mean the choices are about which url is linked to which view or something similar?

Comment: Yest, just that. This information is the relationship between that data like:
{
  "the_url":"the_view"
}